# transpose not working inside arrayformula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to run a query to call all the comments made against the contact number and transpose them automatically throughout the column.
I have tried using arrayformula but it is not working.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Previous meets",IF(isblank(A:A),"",transpose(QUERY(Sheet2!A:C,"select C WHERE B="&A2:A1000&"",0)))))
```

[link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X-uCu6xXaUj4q5k5YRURtl1mXBmp9pW2afKcA6YrXlg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: ctrl+enter? ctrl+shift+enter? shift+enter?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=arrayformula(iferror({unique(Sheet2!B2:B)&"", split(trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(Sheet2!B2:B))=Sheet2!B2:B)*len(Sheet2!B2:B),Sheet2!C2:C&",",),,50000))), ", ")},))
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: thanks it did work. 
Can you give a small commentary on how this formula works

Comment: need help with this sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2MUMw6bg9K55-wHDM8AYIFgdyD7Da5wS0vpIp_CiOU/edit?usp=sharing
need to match the contact number of the visitor to get the previous visit record from master databas

Comment: @tinkershukla: Check cell I6 on the sheet Copy of daily_log.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a list if contacts, in B2 =

```
=arrayformula(split(trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(A2:A10)=Sheet2!B2:B),Sheet2!C2:C&"|",),,COUNTA(Sheet2!C2:C)))),"| "))
```

### Explanation :

- the first step is to build a rectangular grid with by row the elements of the database `Sheet2! B2: B` and by column the elements we are looking for `transpose(A2:A10)`
- at each intersection we are looking if the items are similar `if((transpose(A2:A10)=Sheet2!B2:B)`, if so let's put the comment `Sheet2!C2:C`
- also add a separator that we will use later, say a pipe |
- the smartest trick now is to concatenate the results by column ... use for that the query function (not for selecting anything) and use the third (optional) parameter which is called headers, put the value at the minimum of the number of rows `COUNTA(Sheet2!C2:C))` : all the results will be concatenate in a single cell by column
- final step : transpose, split by the separator and remove the blanks corresponding to the empty cells of the rectangular grid by trim

Comment: In fact, `"select *"` is not necessary since we do not select anything, all the data are considered in the header and then concatenated

Comment: I updated the solution by adding some explanations!